# Double FPS without redundant rendering

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor

I made an animation that is not smooth enough. I'd like to double the number of FPS, without having to re-render everything. What's the best approach to double the number of FPS, render every other frame, and re-assemble the old frames with the new ones?

FWIW, I still have the original png's.

Comment: Hello :). You could first rename your currently rendered files - so frames 1,2,3,4,5 would become 1,3,5,7,9. Then just render with doubled framerate and **uncheck** the Overwrite option.

Comment: But it might not be necessary - even a 15fps animation can look smooth with the right amount of motion blur :).

Comment: they're not perfect, but there are many recent projects for AI video frame interpolation

Comment: @JachymMichal that's actually a great idea, thanks!